# What is a good practice to have an invariant ordering in a real-time commenting system?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, architecture, websocket, real-time

Let's assume this use case:

Bob wants to comment a blog's post.
He is writing: "I'm the first to comment !".

A few milliseconds later, Alice put this comment: "I'm the second !".

Supposing that each posted comment is displayed to the other users by some kind of WebSockets, without refreshing the whole page.
And supposing that the comments list should be ordered by comment's date asc.

Bob should see this:

- Bob: I'm the first
- Alice: I'm the second

**Now supposing the posting of comment is an asynchronous process, meaning as soon as a user clicks on "Send", the list is updated with its entry, not waiting for the server treatment :**

What if the Bob's comment, despite being sent BEFORE Alice's one, is treated (stored) AFTER the Alice's one by the server?

The real display (but not effective on Bob's screen) would be:

- Alice: I'm the second
- Bob: I'm the first

but Bob would see:

- Bob: I'm the first
- Alice: I'm the second

=> It doesn't make sense...Alice typed on her keyboard right after Bob.

A simple refresh of the whole page would display:

- Alice: I'm the second
- Bob: I'm the first

Confusing for Bob !

This would not happen if the server process was synchronous, meaning that the list would be effectively displayed after the server commits the comment.
=> Bob would see Alice's comment appears before his, what is consistent.

How to deal with asynchronous in this case?

Comment: Do not order comments by `id` but by a `create_date` column, server as well as client wise. When a new comment via a `websocket`(or whatever asynchronous connection) arrives use the `create_date` to insert it into the comments.

Comment: Of course yes, but I don't think you well interpreted the issue. Bob's comment is not re-sent to Bob... => so Bob will still see his comment to the top (until he refreshes the whole page), because the `create_date` at client side will always been anterior to Alice's one; even if Alice's one was computed before.

Comment: No he wont as the server relays alices comment to bob, which is then inserted after bobs comment as it has a newer timestamp than bobs. Or you simply send the timestamp of creation from clientside with the comment to the server, check if its realistic(to prevent people from commenting weeks later and altering the timestamp to be first) and either use the client timestamp or generate a new one server side. So you're essentially using the client side timestamps if they're valid.

Comment: I'm pointed out comments are displayed by create-date asc, not desc. So Bob's comment's create-date at his client side, would always been anterior to any other comments without full refresh.

Comment: Alright, I've edited my comment and repaced "before" with "after" since the order makes no difference.

Comment: Bob clicks on "send" at 14000000 ms (date in ms). Alice clicks on "send" at 14000011 ms. So Bob's create-date at client side is anterior to Alice's one. As long as Alice's comment isn't fully processed, Bob just sees his comment (although not processed yet). Now, server fully treats Alice's one and sends a "push" to Bob with the Alice's comment containing a create-date related to the server. Right after that, server fully processes the Bob's comment. => Alice is notified of the Bob's comments, that are well displayed: Alice's comment THEN Bob's comment; but Bob still observes the reverse...

Comment: Furthermore, if I rely on both client dates, I should ensure that Alice date system is exactly the same than Bob date system, that is unlikely true. Leading to other ordering issues. I would have to share a common date : the server date, that would imply Alice and Bob to query this date before putting it as the comment create date=> poor performance

Comment: I really wonder how some great chat systems handle this ordering issue. MSN, Whatsapp etc

Comment: [Timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) are by definition UTC+0 based, so you do not need to ensure anything except that its plausible.

Comment: UTC + 0 based but I already experienced the issue when javascript date ( of now) in computer A is anterior to some ms from javascript date of computer B. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13889853/985949

Comment: This is as close as you can get. If those `few milliseconds off` that you want to have experienced(how exactly did you check that?) are mission critical for your comment system I would advice to get your commenting users all into using a thin client system running over the same thin-client-server to be sure their timestamps are all offset by the same amount of milliseconds...

Comment: What is the difference between a "thin client-server" and retrieving date through a server query before each sending of comment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would Alice know she is the second if Bob's comment didn't exists yet.

For this particular example, if the order is not really relevant for the matter, I would put them in processing order or arrival order. That is the way it is done in majority of blogs and places where you can comment. Actually, it is usual to see the first two or three comments claiming to be the first :D

Now, if order is really relevant, you can use a [optimistic concurrency](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2010/07/16/optimistic-and-pessimistic-concurrency-a-simple-explanation.aspx) approach. Basically, each time you generate the page, you add a hash that identifies the state of the comments; when sending the comment you send that hash as well, and if the page didn't change between the user getting he page and inserting the comment, is all good, you generate the page again with the new comment and with a new hash; otherwise, it will return an "error" that will refresh the comments and warns the user that the page changed and he may need to review the page and current comments before writing the comment.

UPDATE:

IF you want a more reliable/async approach, you can use [vector clocks](http://blog.8thlight.com/rylan-dirksen/2013/10/04/synchronization-in-a-distributed-system.html). But it seems a little overkill for a chat :), probably showing them in arrival order is enough.

Comment: your optimistic solution would imply synchronous calls instead of full async: querying the current hash before sending the comment.

Comment: "I would put them in processing order " => requires synchronous calls ... in order to wait for the server response. What I call full async is : Bob clicks on the button => immediately his comment is inserted in his screen.So cannot get a "processed" date.

Comment: I want a behavior exactly like a Chat.

Comment: No. The hash would be in the page, so when the user gets the page, it gets the hash. When sending a message, attaches the hash to the request. And of course, if your operation is likely to fail because order constraints, it behaves somehow synchronously.

Comment: "In processing order" or in arrival order if you want, like happens on chats.

Comment: I updated my response with a link to distributed clocks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64336/discussion-between-mik378-and-vtortola).

Comment: Sorry, I read and read again your answer, but it doesn't correspond to my OP. I expose my case again:  Bob sends "Hello1". Comments list contain "Hello1" in Bob's screen. Alice sends in a few milliseconds later "Hello2", before receiving "Hello1" (since not processed yet). Alice's screen would contain: "Hello2" THEN "Hello1", whereas it should end up to "Hello1" THEN "Hello2". I can't imagine the use of any hash, since the current hash isn't known by the other part (Alice or Bob).

Comment: Let me put it other way. Each time that the server gives you messages from other participants, it gives you a hash, representing the state of the chat room when that messages arrives. When you send a message, you send the last hash known by you. If the state of the chat room didn't change, the message is added to the chat room and broadcasted to all participants. If otherwise, Alice sends a "Hello2" with the hash previous to "Hello1", the server will tell Alicia that the chatroom changed and she needs to resend the message, since is based on stale information.

Comment: "If the state of the chat room didn't change" => query to the server ... I expected a message immediately appearing in the same page (of the sender of course) as soon as "send" button is clicked. That was the whole point of my OP ;)

Comment: You cannot add the message immediately if the order matters and it is controlled somewhere else.

Comment: ok thanks :) I wondered if there was a possible solution I ignored